# Login with e-mail in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views

I want to authenticate with e-mail and password, but somehow I can't find the setting where it is done?

Here is my `login.html`:

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" maxlength="50" autofocus="autofocus" required=True unique=True class="form-control">
        <label style="margin-top: 1em;" for="password">Passwort</label>
        <input style="margin-bottom: 2em;" id="password" name="password" type="password" maxlength="25" required=True class="form-control">

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="login">Login</button>
```

And here is my `views.py`:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, email=request.email)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(email=mail, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
    return redirect('accounts:view_profile')
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
    args = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

Am I looking completely wrong? Where can I find the setting?

Comment: email = form.cleaned_data.get('eemail') shouldn't be email = form.cleaned_data.get('email') ? and raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1') shouldn't it be  raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')?

Comment: this maybe what you are after 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Comment: @vitor-figueredo yes i edited it. It should be 'email' not 'eemail'. But this 'password1' is correct, because i want change my password later.

Comment: @albinpaul thank you. maybe this helps :)